# Deploying Flask REST API for POST requests + machine learning

Tags: python, flask

I made a REST API that I want to use for deploying machine learning models. The one posted below is a simple one for the iris dataset and it works perfectly offline, but when I upload it to Beanstalk it gives me a HTTP 500 error. This one should take a PUSH request and it doesn't work, but when I made a simpler one with GET request returning "Hello World" it worked. What is wrong with my code below?

Thanks in advance.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from sklearn.externals import joblib

application = Flask(__name__)

iris_path = os.path.join(application.root_path, 'iris.pkl')
iris_model = joblib.load(iris_path, "r")

@application.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def iris():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    sepal_length = float(data['sepal length (cm)'])
    sepal_width = float(data['sepal width (cm)'])
    petal_length = float(data['petal length (cm)'])
    petal_width = float(data['petal width (cm)'])
    response = iris_model.predict([[sepal_length, sepal_width, petal_length, petal_width]]).tolist()
    return jsonify(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(debug = True)
```

I take the model file, python file and requirements file and zip it and then upload it to Elastic Beanstalk, but it doesn't work with post requests.